# Numbering chapter thumbs, removing 0 from toc

Tags: koma-script, chapterthumb

I'm using KOMA-Script for chapter-thumbs. How can I modify it to remove '0' chapter thumb from TOC ?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Chapter thumbs with scrpage2
%
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm
% 
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
% 
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Markus Kohm.
% 
% This work consists of the code until 
% `End of chapter thumbs with scrpage2' only.
% You should not remove the link to the original code:
% <http://www.komascript.de/node/25>.
%

% Safty first
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\let\chapter\undefined
  \chapter must be defined to use chapter thumbs!}{%

% Two new commands for the width and height of the boxes with the
% chapter number at the thumbs (use of commands instead of lengths
% for sparing registers)
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbwidth}{2em}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbheight}{1em}

% Two new commands for the colors of the box background and the
% chapter numbers of the thumbs
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbboxcolor}{black}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbtextcolor}{white}

% New command to set a chapter thumb. I'm using a group at this
% command, because I'm changing the temporary dimension \@tempdima
\newcommand*{\putchapterthumb}{%
  \begingroup
    \Large
    % calculate the horizontal possition of the right paper border
    % (I ignore \hoffset, because I interprete \hoffset moves the page
    % at the paper e.g. if you are using cropmarks)
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{\@oddheadshift}% (internal from scrpage2)
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{-\@tempdima}%
    \addtolength{\@tempdima}{\paperwidth}%
    \addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\oddsidemargin}%
    \addtolength{\@tempdima}{-1in}%
    % putting the thumbs should not change the horizontal
    % possition
    \rlap{%
      % move to the calculated horizontal possition
      \hspace*{\@tempdima}%
      % putting the thumbs should not change the vertical
      % possition
      \vbox to 0pt{%
        % calculate the vertical possition of the thumbs (I ignore
        % \voffset for the same reasons told above)
        \setlength{\@tempdima}{\chapterthumbwidth}%
        \multiply\@tempdima by\value{chapter}%
        \addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\chapterthumbwidth}%
        \addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\baselineskip}%
        % move to the calculated vertical possition
        \vspace*{\@tempdima}%
        % put the thumbs left so the current horizontal possition
        \llap{%
          % and rotate them
          \rotatebox{90}{\colorbox{\chapterthumbboxcolor}{%
              \parbox[c][\chapterthumbheight][c]{\chapterthumbwidth}{%
                \centering
                \textcolor{\chapterthumbtextcolor}{%
                  \strut\thechapter}\\
              }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
        % avoid overfull \vbox messages
        \vss
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

% New command, which works like \lohead but also puts the thumbs (you
% cannot use \ihead with this definition but you may change this, if
% you use more internal scrpage2 commands)
\newcommand*{\loheadwithchapterthumbs}[2][]{%
  \lohead[\putchapterthumb#1]{\putchapterthumb#2}%
}

% initial use
\loheadwithchapterthumbs{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

}
%
%  End of chapter thumbs with scrpage2
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\lohead[]{}` to remove the chapterthumbs and `\loheadwithchapterthumbs{}` to enable them.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{chapterthumbs}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lohead[]{}% no chapterthumbs
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\loheadwithchapterthumbs{}% use chapterthumbs
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But note that package `chapterthumbs` is outdated because it is based on the deprecated package `scrpage2`.

I would suggest to use package `chapterthumb` which can be used with `scrlayer-scrpage`. `chapterthumb.sty` is part of the KOMA-Script book examples. You can download it from https://komascript.de/komascriptbuch5examples. It is in folder "Anhang-B" of the zip file.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}[2016/02/01]
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbwidth}{.05\paperheight}
\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbskip}{.05\paperheight}
\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\thechapter}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Both examples work with the standard class `book` too.

---

If you want to enable and disable the chapter thumbs manually you can define commands which add or remove the layer `chapterthumb` to or from all layer page styles respectively:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}[2016/02/01]
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbwidth}{.05\paperheight}
\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbskip}{.05\paperheight}
\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\thechapter}

\newcommand*\chapterthumbson{%
  \AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}%
}% command to enable chapter thumbs
\newcommand*\chapterthumbsoff{%
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}%
}% command to disable chapter thums
\chapterthumbsoff% disable chapter thumbs
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\clearpage
\chapterthumbson% enable chapter thumbs
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks I will use it but when I'm applying your sample I'm getting:
Package scrlayer Error: cannot define '\newpagestyle'. See the scrlayer package documentation for explanation.

Comment: With my example or with your code? There is no MWE in your question. Maybe you load another package for page header and footer too? `titleps`? Note that this package can not be used together with `chapterthumb` (or `chapterthumbs`). The chapter thumbs are realized by pagestyles defined by `scrlayer-scrpage`/`scrlayer` (or `scrpage2`).

Comment: Thanks, you were right, I had too many packages included, I have removed some of them and it's working. I have 3 chapters but I want chapterthumb numeration to start with second chapter, how can I do that?

Comment: I have added a suggestion that allowes to enable and disable the chapter thumbs manually.

Comment: It's only removing chapter thumb from first chapter. I want second chapter to start with 1st chapter thumb numeration.

Comment: So there should be a not the chapter number in the chapter thumb? You want to use a different counter?

Comment: Yep, I want to use a different counter. Let 1st chapter thumb appear on 2nd chapter.

Comment: Replace `\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\thechapter}` by `\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\the\numexpr\thechapter-1\relax}` or use an own counter inside `\chapterthumbformat`.

Comment: It helped, but I noticed other thing. I'm getting no chapter thumb on the last page before the indexes. `\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\input{kodeks}
\chapterthumbsoff % disable chapter thumbs
\chapter{DZIAŁ I. PRZEPISY OGÓLNE}
\chapterthumbson % enable chapter thumbs
\input{dz1roz1}
\chapter{DZIAŁ II. POSTĘPOWANIE}
\input{dz2roz1}
\input{dz2roz2}
\chapterthumbsoff % disable chapter thumbs
\printindex 
\end{document} `

Comment: Use a `\clearpage` before `\chapterthumbsoff`.